# What's the math formula converting a smaller number to larger decimal and vice-versa?

Tags: math, decimal, formula

Here's an image that describes exactly what I'm looking for, the numbers are irrelevant just for example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/414973/num_conversion.jpg

Say I have a decimal range from 1.2 to 5.4 and a range of numbers from 200 to 212 and I want 212 to represent 1.2 and 200 to represent 5.4 and then breaking down the numbers in that range via a formula.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Answer (score 0):

instead of `1.2` and `5.4` suppose we have `x` and `y` and instead of `200` and `212` suppose we have `A` and `B`. now just consider :

```
diff = B - A
sec = (y - x) / diff
```

and a number like `A < C < B` will be represented by : **`sec * (C - A) + x`**.

**Example :**

```
x = 1.2
y = 5.4

A = 200
B = 212
```

then

```
diff = 12
sec = 4.2/12 = 0.35
```

so if you want a number to represent 210 it would be :

```
sec * (C - A) + x = 0.35 * 10 + 1.2 = 4.7
```